# Javascript how to pass variable to URL query with window.open

Tags: javascript, url

First of all - this question has no answers at
[Include variable in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200850/include-variable-in-url) 
or [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)
I tested many variants from elsewhere before my question here.
For example, as advised at [Include variable in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200850/include-variable-in-url)

```
window.open('http://example.com/?q="+ myname"');
```

does not work with the script below.
A kind of specific wrapping is needed.

So, simplest script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendquery() {
var myname = "John";
alert(myname);
window.open('http://example.com/?q=(myname)');
}
</script>
<button onclick="sendquery()">Query</button>
```

Alert perfectly shows variable John. But query sends not variable John but (myname).

Or + myname - if follow other answers.

How to wrap variable to URL query ?

Comment: Basic string concatenation. `window.open('http://example.com/?q='+ myname);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string concatenation is not correct

```
var myname = "test"
window.open("http://example.com/?q=" + myname); // Classic string concatenation
window.open(`http://example.com/?q=${myname}`); // Using template literal
```

Comment: Thx for hint, I've sorted many similar variations but not literal ! Solved !

Comment: You were first :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're just putting the variable in the string incorrectly. Check out [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you don't need to support IE.

---

```
var myname = "John";
// won't work
window.open('http://example.com/?q="+ myname"');
// will produce 'http://example.com/?q=John'
window.open(`http://example.com/?q=${myname}`);
```

and likewise

```
// won't work
window.open('http://example.com/?q=(myname)');
// valid
window.open(`http://example.com/?q=${myname}`);
```

If you do need to support IE then `window.open('http://example.com/?q=' + myname);` should work

Comment: Thx everybody for hint, I've sorted many similar variations but not literal ! Solved and work with Microsoft Edge, at-least...

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the URL in [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
window.open(`http://example.com/?q=${myname}`);
```

Comment: You don't "have to". You can use simple concatenation.

Comment: Well "have to" should be "Should have to". The cleanest way of doing concatenation is the Template Literals

Comment: That's an opinion. I think `a + "test"` is cleaner than a${test} (<-- not sure how to put back-tick in an SO comment so that it actually appears as opposed to formats the contents as code).